# Custom adapter in coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

When I try to fill a ListView using a custom adapter, I get an empty list, I can't figure out what the error is? Why is everything loaded and displayed when using the default adapter?

> HeroesAdapter.kt

```kotlin
    class HeroesAdapter(context: Context, heroes: List<TestHero>): BaseAdapter() {
            private val context = context
            private val heroes = heroes
        
            override fun getCount(): Int {
                return heroes.count()
            }
        
            override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
                return heroes[position]
            }
        
            override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
                return 0
            }
        
            override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        
                   // categoryView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_heroes, null)
                val categoryView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_heroes, parent, false)
                   // val categoryImage: ImageView = categoryView.findViewById(R.id.heroesImageView)
                    val categoryText: TextView = categoryView.findViewById(R.id.textHeroView)
                    val category = heroes[position]
        
                    categoryText.text = category.global.name
        
                    return categoryView
        
            }
        }
```

> HeroesActivity

```
class HeroesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var adapter : ArrayAdapter<TestHero>
    lateinit var adapt: ArrayAdapter<String>
    lateinit var heroesAdapt : HeroesAdapter
    var listHero = ArrayList<TestHero>()
    private val TAG = "HeroesActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_heroes)



       // val adapterr = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,)


        adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            LinkedList<TestHero>())
       // heroesListView.adapter = adapter

        adapt = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            LinkedList<String>())
        //heroesListView.adapter = adapt


        getCurrentData()

        heroesAdapt = HeroesAdapter(this, listHero)
        heroesListView.adapter = heroesAdapt

    }

    private fun getCurrentData() {
        val api = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ApiRequest::class.java)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = api.herList().awaitResponse()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val data = response.body()!!
                Log.d(TAG, data.toString())

                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                   // adapter.add(data.global.name)
                    adapt.add(data.global.platform)

                    listHero.add(data)

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks for the answer. You can release as an answer, and I close the topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you add data to the backing list of the adapter (`listHero.add(data)`), but you never inform the adapter that its backing data has changed (`heroesAdapt.notifyDataSetChanged()`).

As an aside, there are some issues with your coroutine. You should not use GlobalScope. Use `lifecycleScope` instead to avoid leaking network calls and copies of your Activity. Really, you should fetch data in a ViewModel using the ViewModel's scope and expose it via LiveData or SharedFlow so the network call doesn't have to restart if the phone rotates.